# UserManager error "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, blazor

In my Blazor Server-side app, I have multiple components which each use the UserManager via dependency injection that are often rendered on the same page. For example, I use the UserManager in the NavMenu to show/hide certain navigation items from the user, then have logic within the pages themselves to prevent navigation to those same pages in the pages themselves. Often when navigating to a page that has this logic, the NavMenu and Page UserManager are appearing to collide, resulting in the error:

```
InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
```

I am sure that this is an issue others have run into, but haven't been able to find a solution. This occurs most often if I hit Refresh on a page containing multiple components with an injected UserManager. I appreciate any help that can be provided, and can provide more information if needed!

Per request, here is my registration of the UserManager. ApplicationUserManager is currently not actually overriding any functionality in the UserManager, just implemented for future customization/enhancements:

```
            services.AddIdentity<WS7.Engine.Models.Identity.ApplicationUser, WS7.Engine.Models.Identity.ApplicationRole>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WS7.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationIdentityContext>()
            .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
            .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
            .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Possibly worth noting, the calls that seem to be blowing out with this error (based on the stack trace) are both in the OnInitializedAsync() methods of the various components involved.

Example of two components:
Component 1:

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        await Authorize();
    }

    private async Task Authorize()
    {
        bool allowNavigate = (AllowedRoleIds.Count() == 0);
        var contextUser = _AuthorizeHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
        if (contextUser != null)
        {
            var user = await _AuthorizeUserManager.GetUserAsync(contextUser);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var result = await _AuthorizeIdentityService.GetUserRightsAsync(new Engine.Models.GetUserRightsParams()
                {
                    UserID = user.Id
                });
                if (result.Succeeded == Engine.Models.Base.SuccessState.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (result.UserRightIDs.Any(uri => AllowedRoleIds.Split(",").Any(ari => ari.Equals(uri, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))))
                    {
                        allowNavigate = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (allowNavigate == false)
        {
            _AuthorizeNavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login");
        }
    }
```

Component 2:

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await RefreshData();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private async Task RefreshData()
    {
        var userAccountsResult = await _IdentityService.GetAspNetUserAccountsAsync(new Engine.Models.GetAspNetUserAccountsParams()
        {
            //Return all. Don't set any Params
        });
        if (userAccountsResult.Succeeded == SuccessState.Succeeded)
        {
            var users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
            var usersView = users.Select(u => new UserViewModel()
            {
                Id = u.Id,
                UserName = u.UserName,
                FirstName = u.FirstName,
                LastName = u.LastName,
                Email = u.Email,
                AccountStatus = u.ApprovedStatus,
                EmailConfirmed = u.EmailConfirmed,
                Active = !u.InActive,
                UserAccounts = userAccountsResult.UserAccounts.Where(ua => ua.UserID == u.Id).Select(ua => new UserAccountModel()
                {
                    Account = ua.Account
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

            Users = usersView;
            FilteredUsers = usersView;
        }
        else
        {
            _StatusService.SetPageStatusMessage(new PageStatusMessageEventArgs()
            {
                AlertType = AlertType.Danger,
                Message = "There was an issue initializing the page."
            });

        }

    }
```

Stack Trace of an example exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913. at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at WS7.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationUserManager.FindByIdAsync(String userId) in C:\VB6\Web\WS7\WS7\Areas\Identity\Data\ApplicationUserManager.cs:line 31 at WS7.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationUserManager.GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal) in C:\VB6\Web\WS7\WS7\Areas\Identity\Data\ApplicationUserManager.cs:line 35 at WS7.Components.PDAuthorizeBase.Authorize() in C:\VB6\Web\WS7\WS7\Components\PDAuthorizeBase.cs:line 51 at WS7.Components.PDAuthorizeBase.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\VB6\Web\WS7\WS7\Components\PDAuthorizeBase.cs:line 35
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have added my UserManager registration code to the main post. Also, I don't believe I have any missing awaits or have any async voids, but I will re-review my project. I don't have any warnings showing up in my "Errors List" window in visual studio.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have examples for two colliding components. Thanks!

Comment: @HenkHolterman Also, to clarify, the _IdentityService object is a service which does certain Identity-adjacent operations via a WebApi - data retrieval/manipulation which cannot be done with the user manager (such as custom tables management)

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have added a stack trace to the end of my post. Thanks!

Comment: The UserManager is the only DBContext that is accessible within the WS7 project; everything else is currently handled via WebAPI in a separate project. Isn't the UserManager always a singleton? Is there a way to declare it otherwise? I have a handful of calls to GetUserID or GetUserName non-async since the Async versions don't accept a ClaimsPrincipal object - could those be related? I added it in the post, but this primarily occurs when I refresh the page and create a new connection to the server.

Comment: Just to prevent confusion, I meant that the UserManager is the only thing being used to "directly" communicate with the database, not that it is a DBContext. The other DBContext I have is being used via the WebApi and WebApi calls.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might find a solution to your issue here:

> You should use `OwningComponentBase<T>` in these situations. Below is an
>   updated sample that shows the right pattern.

[Read this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16745#issuecomment-549505605). [See also this...](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18340)

Are you using HttpContext in your Server Blazor App ? If you does, you shouldn't,
as Server Blazor App are not HTTP-based apps, but WebSocket-based ones.

Hope this helps...

Comment: If I understand correctly, according to the sample project provided in the links, switching my components to OwningComponentBase<ApplicationUserManager> and injecting the UserManager is supposed to resolve this issue? I attempted this without success. Also, I am currently getting the HTTPContext via the IHttpContextAccessor. Is the correct way using the AuthenticationStateProvider?

Comment: Sorry, but right now I cannot help you with the main issue in question as I'm rather busy now. However, I'd suggest that you alter the scope of the DBContext. The following link is to my post how to access the HttpContext when your app is initially accessed, before the WebSocket connection is established, which is the only time the HttpContext is available. Regarding your question about the AuthenticationStateProvider, the answer is yes. You have to learn how to use this service and other related component, very seriously. This is the way to go in Blazor.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on AuthenticationStateProvider! Is there a way to alter the scope of the DBContext within the UserManager? I have attempted to do so without success so far.